# Переделать условия с if используя тернарный оператор

Tags: php, тернарный-оператор

есть массив `$arr = array('1a','2b','4c','5d','3g');`
и есть проверка массива на начальный символ каждого элемента

```
foreach ($arr as $element){
    if (substr($element, 0, 1) == 1) echo "one";
    elseif (substr($element, 0, 1) == 2) echo " two ";
    elseif (substr($element, 0, 1) == 4) echo $element;
    elseif (substr($element, 0, 1) != 3 && substr($element, 0, 1) != 1 && substr($element, 0, 1) != 2) echo " not one, two or three";
}
```

нужно упростить, заменив `if` и `==` на тернарный оператор
помогите плз, голову ломаю долго

Comment: вас в коде не смущает вызов `substr($element, 0, 1)` написанный 6 раз?

Comment: а `switch` уже не в моде?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach ($arr as $element){
  $first = substr($element, 0, 1);
  $toEcho =
    ($first == 1)? "one" : (
      ($first == 2)? "two" : (
        ($first == 4)? $element : (
          ($first != 3)? "not one, two or three" : ""
        )
      )
    );
  if (!empty($toEcho))
    echo $toEcho;
}
```

Comment: `$toEcho != ""` можно заменить на `!empty($toEcho)`